# In JavaScript, how can I test if any AJAX call is running in the background at a given moment?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm bound to use native javascript (although a jQuery solution can also work if I convert it to native javascript).

Also, I have no handles to existing AJAX requests so I can't access them directly.

I am searching for something like:

```
var ajaxRequestsInProgress = document.getAllAjaxRunning();
ajaxRequestsInProgress[1].getStatus(); // will return the status of the request, for example
```

so I can access this object and check / manipulate existing ajax requests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is, shall we say, a little tricky. There is no native way to do it. So we need to do a bit of hacking, modifying the native `XMLHttpRequest` functions. Something like this:

```
var getAJAXRequests = (function() {
    var oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
        currentRequests = [];

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        currentRequests.push(this); // add this request to the stack
        oldSend.apply(this, arguments); // run the original function

        // add an event listener to remove the object from the array
        // when the request is complete
        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            var idx;

            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                idx = currentRequests.indexOf(this);
                if (idx > -1) {
                    currentRequests.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            }
        }, false);
    };

    return function() {
        return currentRequests;
    }
}());
```

It can be called with `getAJAXRequests()`.

You can see it in action [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Jf4/2/).

Comment: Very nice approach! By "redefining" the send() method, you are working in the basement, enabling you to keep track of *any* XMLHttpRequest - no matter by which framework or addon it has been issued.

Comment: Would it make sense to move the line oldSend.apply after this.addEventListener ? It would seem impossible for the response to come back before the event listener was added, but maybe it's theoretically possible?

Answer (score -2):

I know you didn't specifically ask for a `Mootools` solution, but I've done something similar which I thought I'd share here for others' reference. I achieve this by overriding the various request methods. I'm currently using version 1.5.1, but this or something similar should work on other versions.

```
(function() {
    var requestCounter = 0,
        send = Request.prototype.send,
        cancel = Request.prototype.cancel,
        onSuccess = Request.prototype.onSuccess,
        onFailure = Request.prototype.onFailure,
        timeout = Request.prototype.timeout;

    var increment = function() {
        ++requestCounter;
    };

    var decrement = function() {
        --requestCounter;

        if (requestCounter < 0) {
            requestCounter = 0;
        }
    };

    Request.implement({
        send: function() {
            increment();
            return send.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        cancel: function() {
            decrement();
            return cancel.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        onSuccess: function() {
            decrement();
            return onSuccess.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        onFailure: function() {
            decrement();
            return onFailure.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        timeout: function() {
            decrement();
            return timeout.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });

    Request.getRunningCount = function() {
        return requestCounter;
    };
})();
```

Now every time a request is made, the counter will increment and when it's complete, it will decrement.

```
var request1 = new Request(...);
var request2 = new Request(...);

request1.send();
request2.send();
console.log(Request.getRunningCount()); // 2

request1.cancel();
console.log(Request.getRunningCount()); // 1

// request2 completes
console.log(Request.getRunningCount()); // 0
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I disagree that my response was that far off - the only difference is it isn't native javascript. Otherwise, it's extremely close to the response above. Also, the fact that I came looking for an answer and ran across this post, I thought I'd provide a similar, but slightly different alternative for others in the future.